# Which filesystems can RHEL 5 read from and write to?

Tags: filesystems, rhel

Which filesystems can RHEL 5 read from and write to? Are there any that work but not well? I'm partitioning and external hard drive and I haven't been able to find a comprehensive list anywhere.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Supporting_operating_systems

Comment: That has a category for "linux", but I want to know about RHEL 5 specifically. For example, I've found that it apparently had issues with ext3 in the past. Does it still have them?

Comment: What issues with ext3? `ext3` had been stable for a long time when RHEL 5 was released.

Comment: On further investigation, the problem appeared to be people who just didn't know how to partition a hard drive asking questions online that made it sound like they were having problems.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend partitioning an external drive with `ext3` unless you are _sure_ you will only ever use it with *nix. See [here](http://superuser.com/a/465679/151431) for a discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ext2, 3, 4, VFAT (as vonbrand mentioned), GFS, and XFS are supported.

http://www.redhat.com/f/pdf/RHEL6_FileSystem_WP_5677547_0311_dm_web.pdf

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/pdf/Global_File_System/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-5-Global_File_System-en-US.pdf

Answer (score 1):

ext3 is native, I believe; VFAT is safe too (but very limiting). Check what filesystem the rest of the machine uses...